# Scale image proportionally to fit current document dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, image-resizing, jquery-events

I have an image with some dimension `alfa` x `beta` pixels.

Then `onDocumentReady` and `onWindowResize` I calculate current document dimensions.

Task is to scale image proportionally until one of dimensions is reached.

Comment: If it's a background-image, and you don't care about <IE8, check out the CSS3 property: `background-size: contain;`

Comment: @ahren Thanks, it was new to me! :) But I still have to care about <IE8, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    scaleStart();

});

$(window).resize(function() {

    scaleStart();

});

function scaleStart() {

    $("#myImage").css("min-width", 0);
    $("#myImage").css("min-height", 0);

    var originalWidth = 1762;
    var originalHeight = 1041;

    var safeWidth = $(document).width() - 100;
    var safeHeight = $(document).height() - 100;

    var scaleWidth = originalWidth / safeWidth;
    var scaleHeight = originalHeight / safeHeight;

    if (scaleWidth > scaleHeight)
    {
        $("#myImage").css("min-width", originalWidth / scaleWidth);
        $("#myImage").css("min-height", originalHeight / scaleWidth);
    }

    else
    {
        $("#myImage").css("min-width", originalWidth / scaleHeight);
        $("#myImage").css("min-height", originalHeight / scaleHeight);
    }

}
```